# varnishlog only specific pool or req.url

Tags: varnish

I want to make my debugging easier and view only stuff going through a specific pool or `req.url`.

Manual was not helpful or I missed the helpful lines.

`grep` is not a convenient help as it would cut lines I need.

Comment: Unclear what I'm asking? If it's unclear to you, doesn't mean the question itself is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `varnishlog` query language. The examples in the documentation are pretty poor so I believe your question is good.

You can query in **varnishlog** using `-q`. With it it is possible to query any Varnish variable. An example of querying the a url `/log/test.html` :

`varnishlog -q 'ReqURL eq "/log/test.html"'`

This would retrieve the whole log of the requests to `/log/test.html`